# Replace dynamic text in a text block - PLSQL - REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

how can I replace a text in plsql which does not know the current position or the length of the phrase, nor the position is known because it can be dynamic.

the possible solutions that I have been able to reach is the following, I have tried it in online platforms of regex and it gives me the expected result, but when I implement it I get unexpected values.

the pattern I have found is that most of the time it either ends in `,` or `;` or a `space` and almost always the word `USO:`, for example: `FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX;` USO:

words to extract or replace:

- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y
  EMPAQUE: BOTELLA ALUMINIO POR: 5KG, 10 KG, 20 KG, 25KG, 50KG, 100 gr,
  250 gr, 500 gr, 300gr - CAJAS POR: 10 KG , 15 KG, 20 KG, 25 KG,
  50LB,  - TAMBOR POR: 25 KG, 50 KG, 5KG, 50 LB, 180 KG, 20KG, 4KG -
  GARRAFA POR: 10 KG , 25 KG, 20 KG, 5KG, 10 KG, 1 KG,  - SACOS POR: 20
  KG, 25KG, 50LB, 10KG - FRASCOS POR: 25gr, 250gr, 500gr, 100gr, 250gr,
  1 KG, 300gr, 1000gr - TARROS POR: 1000gr, 20 gr, 25gr, 100 gr,
  2500gr, 250gr, 500gr, 50gr, 1KG. ;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE/
  PRESENTACION COMERCIAL: CAJAS DE 15KG // 20KG //  25KG // SACOS DE
  22.68KG // FRASCOS DE 0.05KG // 0.025KG // 0.10KG // 0.25KG // 0.50KG // 0.30 KG // 1KG;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX PENDT XXXX;
- FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: *** PENDIENTE
  ***;

text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit tortor non erat rhoncus, ac fermentum eros blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ullamcorper tellus non nulla suscipit, et eleifend eros sagittis. Aenean iaculis eu mauris at egestas. Nullam ac interdum libero. In  `FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX;` USO: volutpat venenatis ullamcorper. In tempus lorem vel turpis lacinia ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut eleifend nulla magna, ut malesuada quam dapibus vitae. Mauris et molestie libero.

Regex:

`^.*?(FORMA\sDE\sPRESENTACI[OÓ]?N\sY\sEMPAQUE(?:(?:[\/\s]+)PRESENTACI[OÓ]N\sCOMERCIAL)?(?:[\:\s[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ,0-9;\.%*\t\-]+)[,;]\s)(?:[U]).*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tCbwNR/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Oracle does not support non-capturing groups `(?:)`, just use a capturing group `()` or no group
- `[\/\s]` will match a single character that is either `\` or `/` or `\` or `s` which is probably not what you want; you probably want to omit the escape character (as it isn't escaping anything) and use the POSIX character set `[:space:]` like this `[/[:space:]]`

So your regular expression would be:

```sql
^.*?(FORMA\sDE\sPRESENTACI[OÓ]?N\sY\sEMPAQUE([/[:space:]]+PRESENTACI[OÓ]N\sCOMERCIAL)?[:[:space:]A-Za-zÀ-ÿ,0-9;\.%*\t\-]+[,;]\s)U.*$
```

*Note: do not use regex101 to test Oracle regular expressions; it does not use the same regular syntax as Oracle so your regular expressions are not always going to work.*

---

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum suscipit tortor non erat rhoncus, ac fermentum eros blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ullamcorper tellus non nulla suscipit, et eleifend eros sagittis. Aenean iaculis eu mauris at egestas. Nullam ac interdum libero. In FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX; USO: volutpat venenatis ullamcorper. In tempus lorem vel turpis lacinia ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut eleifend nulla magna, ut malesuada quam dapibus vitae. Mauris et molestie libero.' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^.*?(FORMA\sDE\sPRESENTACI[OÓ]?N\sY\sEMPAQUE([/[:space:]]+PRESENTACI[OÓ]N\sCOMERCIAL)?[:[:space:]A-Za-zÀ-ÿ,0-9;\.%*\t\-]+[,;]\s)U.*$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS match
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

| MATCH |
| --- |
| FORMA DE PRESENTACIÓN Y EMPAQUE: XXX; |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6h_0EkV0)